# How to make shear transform in tensorflow like tensorflow.image.random_flip_left_right(image)?

Tags: tensorflow, transform

In keras, you can make shear transform by `random_shear` in `keras.preprocessing.image`.

But how to make shear transform in tensorflow?

What I want is something like `tensorflow.image.random_flip_left_right(image)` in tensorflow.

Comment: Isn't it like among the first google search results with relevant keywords? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/random_shear

Comment: I have try it. But in tensorflow.image.random_flip_left_right(image),image is a type of tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor,random_shear process type of numpy array.

Comment: It will be done by tf.contrib.image.transform